# Multiple disjoint classes in rdf range constraint

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, rdfs, inference

I want to define multiple classes (with limited inferencing) as the range of an owl objecttypeproperty. Let me explain in detail by providing you an example.

I have two classes: Furniture and Device, which are not disjoint, i.e., another subclass/instance can inherit from both classes, e.g., Lamp can be a furniture and device.

Now I would like to define an OWL objecttypeproperty: hasComponent that can only accept range as either :Furniture or :Device, NOT both.

```
:hasComponent rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
         rdf:type owl:TransitiveProperty ;
         rdfs:range :Furniture ,
                    :Device .
```

When I create an instance using the property:

```
:furniture1 rdf:type :furniture .
:device1 rdf:type :device .
:furtniture1 :hasComponent :lamp .
```

The inferencing engine will infer that :device1 is a :furniture, which I dont want, because I have already defined that device1 is a device.

One solution is to remove  rdf:range and explicitly define the instance types, but I  did not want to remove the range because it will limit the scope of the search space.

Comment: The default interpretation of multiple ranges is the intersection of those. What you need is OWL, i.e. `òwl:unionOf`. See the specs for details.

Comment: Thanks, Do you mean that I declare it directly like this :hasComponent rdfs:range owl:unionOf (:furniture  :device)  . OR do I need to create a separate union class and use the class a range, e.g., _:x1 rdf:type owl:Class ; owl:unionOf (:furniture  :device) . :hasComponent rdfs:range _:x1 .

Comment: You can do this, but it's not necessary as an OWL class expression can be used as the range of an object property: ` :p rdfs:range [a owl:Class ; owl:unionOf(:A :B :C ...) ] . `

Comment: I forgot that you said "not both". In general, OWL doesn't have constraints but axioms that can be used to infer new knowledge. In your case, it's more correct to introduce another class for the range that is the *disjoint union* of both.

Comment: Feels like the issue is more complex than that. X can be Furniture or Device but not both, but there are individuals that are both and they should be excluded. So, the class should be ((Furniture or Device) and not (Furniture and Device)), i.e., their symmetric difference.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a union class of all the classes involved and subtract their intersection (example: `((Furniture or Device) and not (Furniture and Device))`) and set that class as the range. The same approach needs to be used for domains.

You can declare this as a named class, or insert it (with the necessary RDF/XML structure around it) directly into the range axiom. I would think you'll probably need the same class in multiple places, so a named class might be the best solution.

Comment: Hi Ignazio. Given that both classes are not disjoint in general, I guess having an additional class for the range that is the disjoint union of both would be better. What do you think? Can you change your answer maybe? Cheers!

Comment: A disjoint union is a partition of the class, and in this context the desired ranges are neither disjoint nor a partition. I think the only part of my answer that requires changing is the mention of disjoint classes - it's any classes, really.

Comment: Hm, let me explain why I said this: He said "Furniture and Device, which are not disjoint". So I understand this as those must not be declared disjoint in the whole ontology because he wants to add subclasses/instances to both later on. Then he said "accept range as either :Furniture or :Device, NOT both" For me, this sounds like XOR

Comment: Agreed on that, that's why in my other comment i described the symmetric difference as a solution - same as XOR.

Comment: However disjoint union has ulterior implications, as it both states that the component classes are disjoint and that their union covers the whole extension of the (named) class. I don't think having a named class is a requirement here, and the disjoint and coverage parts do not apply either.

Comment: Ok, thank's for the explanation. I agree with you. I hope the TO understands that OWL reasoning will be needed and domain/range are not constraints like in databases. Cheers.